# Trying to create a data dump with week on week data, but large date range is giving over all data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this  code, which is supposed to give me hours week on week for people who were newly active in that week, however when I'm add a bigger date range such Jan - till date the data extracted gets added on with previously active people too because of the first trip filter I have added.

Now I understand my problem, but I dont know how to fix it.

```
select f.city
     , sum(if((date(first_trip_date) between date('{{start_date}}') and date('{{end_date}}') ),d.has_trip,0)) New_Active_Caps
     , sum(if((date(first_trip_date) between date('{{start_date}}') and date('{{end_date}}') ),d.available_hours,0)) New_Avl_Hrs
     , week(d.day) week
     , month(d.day) month
  from prod_agg.captain_stats_daily d
  join prod_dwh.captain_funnel f 
    on f.captain_id = d.captain_id
 where f.country = 'Pakistan' 
   and date(d.day) between date('{{start_date}}') and date('{{end_date}}')  
   and f.city = 'Islamabad'
 group 
    by 1,4,5
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would all be helpful.

Comment: A http://sqlfiddle.com/ will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that functions cannot use indexes, so you might want to rethink the range condition

Comment: Hi Guys, I'm sorry for the mistakes, I'm a little new to sql and don't have Computer Science background. But to answer the questions above, I'm looking for contribution of hours from "captains who joined in week X" v " old captains who joined before week X". 

But because of the large data range, old active data gets clubbed with the new one. I need to figure out a better way to filter it.